# How can I eager load one:many:one navigation properties in Entity Framework without using magic strings?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I'm looking for a way to specify complex navigation properties when eager loading entities using Entity Framework v6.1.3

In my scenario, a `Customer` has many `SalesOrders` and a `SalesOrder` has exactly one `DeliveryAddress`

The relevant snippets of entity code are :

```
public class Customer {      
  public virtual ICollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrder {
  public Customer Customer { get;set; }
  public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  public virtual ICollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

I now need to implement a method that will eager-load a customer, including all of their orders and the delivery addresses for those orders.

I can do this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {

  public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

  public Customer LoadCustomerIncludingSalesOrders(int customerId) {
    var customer = Customers
      .Include("SalesOrders")
      .Include("SalesOrders.DeliveryAddress")
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerId);
    return customer;
  }
```

}

but having to specify the navigation properties to be loaded using magic strings is causing all sorts of headaches with renaming bits of the model.

I know EF also supports specifying navigation properties using an expression, but I have no idea how to specify the Customer > SalesOrder > DeliveryAddress association using expressions like this. Is it possible?

```
public Customer LoadCustomerIncludingSalesOrders(int customerId) {
  var customer = Customers.
    .Include(c => c.SalesOrders)

    .Include(c => /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE? */)

    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerId);
  return customer;
}
```

Comment: One way to make the string variant a bit nicer would be to use `nameof`.

Comment: If you hover lambda overload of `Include` in VS, you'll see a whole help topic describing how to use it for different scenarios, including yours. Basically you need to use `Select`s inside, e.g. `Include(c => c.SalesOrder.Select(so => so.DeliveryAddress))`

Comment: @IvanStoev that's absolutely perfect. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Comment: @DylanBeattie I'm pretty sure it's a dupe (I'm just lazy to search), so let keep it this way. Glad it helped though :)

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan Stoev points out in his comment, the syntax I need here is:

```
public Customer LoadCustomerIncludingSalesOrders(int customerId) {
 var customer = Customers.
   .Include(c => c.SalesOrders)
   .Include(c => c.SalesOrders.Select(so => so.DeliveryAddress))
   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerId);
  return customer;
}
```